# Requesting OAuth2 tokens from a node server using react-native

Tags: node.js, react-native, oauth-2.0, fetch-api

As part of learning about OAuth2 and persistent login with react-native, I'm using the OAuth2 server example found [here](https://github.com/pedroetb/node-oauth2-server-example) to figure out how to send info and request validation from the server.

At the moment, I'd just like to be able to log the access_token to the console as I think I can then build on that knowledge on my own. I just can't seem to find an ideal example of how this can fetch correctly.

I think the part I'm not getting is the sending of `header` and `body` information.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  goGetToken() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/oauth/token/?grant_type=password&username=pedroetb&password=password', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic YXBwbGljYXRpb246c2VjcmV0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
    }).then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        console.log(responseJson.access_token);
        return responseJson.access_token;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.goGetToken();
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <View></View>
    )
  }
}
```

The included readme suggests the following, but I can't seem to find an example of sending headers/fetch correctly?

```
### Obtaining a token

To obtain a token you should POST to `http://localhost:3000/oauth/token`.

#### With *password* grant

You need to include the client credentials in request headers and the user credentials and grant type in request body:

* **Headers**
    * **Authorization**: `"Basic " + clientId:secret base64'd`
        * (for example, to use `application:secret`, you should send `Basic YXBwbGljYXRpb246c2VjcmV0`)

    * **Content-Type**: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
* **Body**
    * `grant_type=password&username=pedroetb&password=password`
        * (contains 3 parameters: `grant_type`, `username` and `password`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently work with OAuth 2 in React native and I found a really good blog talking about it. It's also have a github repo for reference. Hope it can help you.

https://medium.com/@alexmngn/the-essential-boilerplate-to-authenticate-users-on-your-react-native-app-f7a8e0e04a42

Comment: Thanks for this, looks like a nice project.

Comment: do you mind me asking if you had any trouble getting it up and running? There are a couple of depreciated packages that can be replaced, Which I've managed successfully, but the only thing that didn't work for me is the registration of a user. I get an error relating to a failed promise.

Comment: actually I just use it for reference. I just read the blog to get some more info. But can you show me an error. I will try to help

Comment: Thanks, I decided to build something like this from the ground up, starting with simple fetch(RN) and response (Node). I'll start adding each additional feature once the first one is working.

Comment: Yeah :D it's much more better than clone someone source for your :D glad that you make it worked

Comment: This one was buried but  is part of the docs for oauth it's very clear as an example for setting it up. https://github.com/oauthjs/express-oauth-server/tree/master/examples/postgresql